# How do I save the value of date picker into a variable?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I'm making a To-Do app and I want the value of the date picker as saved by the user into a variable so that I can print that variable in a tableView.

This is my datePicker code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
    datePicker.locale = Locale.current
    datePicker.setValue(UIColor.gray, forKeyPath: "textColor")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a specific target to you Picker in order to get a new value.
For example :

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    var selectedDate : Date?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.storeSelectedRow), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    }

    func storeSelectedRow(){

        self.selectedDate = self.datePicker.date
    }
```

#### OR

**With the storyboard:**
As you add you `pickerView` as a `@IBOutlet` you can add a `@IBAction` to your view controller and then get the date of your picker and store it to a variable.

Please see this example that pass the Picker Value to another ViewController
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2RAeG6eqtvCbWp1VE5IZ0E2Vkk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry I am learning, but where is the value saved of the datePicker ? I mean I want to Print it in a Label in another ViewController, how do I do that ?

Comment: No worry :) Here the value is saved in the "current" _ViewController_. In order to pass it to an other one you can, for example, use a _segue_ and use _prepareForSegue_ function to pass the data. For Example : [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2RAeG6eqtvCbWp1VE5IZ0E2Vkk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Like you have ShowVC in you VC that segues to the destination VC and it displays the date selected. I am making this reminder app in which this is the 2nd step when you choose the time, I still have 2 more steps VC to show. So I want the saved date in a variable which I can call in a TableView Label which displays the time.

Answer (score 0):

Add follow code in viewDidLoad.

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "dateChanged:",
        forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Then get value in func dateChanged.

```
     func dateChanged(datePicker : UIDatePicker){

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    //formatter
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy年MM月dd日 HH:mm:ss"
    print(formatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date))

    //there you get your label first
    //let label = ...
    label.text = formatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
}
```

Comment: how do I take the changed value to my TableView and print it in a Label ?

Comment: lable.text = formatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)

Comment: You can add this code in func "dateChanged", but you should get label first.

Comment: label for the date which is to be displayed in the TabkeView?